# Can I use the SimpleMembershipProvider with a different table to UserProfiles?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, entity-framework-5, simplemembership

First of all, I only want one database, not an extra silly little thing for credentials. I have read that this provider uses the `UserProfiles` table to store login credentials. I would like to use my `Occupant` table, and not have to link the two. Is this possible, and how do I do it?

If it must be `UserProfile`, could I perhaps inherit `Occupant` from that using EF inheritence features, so the provider sees only a `UserProfile` interface on my `Occupant` table?

Comment: as I recall, there's an interface you can implement and configure in for it. I'd have to check my latest project that uses it. Tweet me later to remind me, if I forget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the name of the table to use in the [*WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569134%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method.  There is a parameter in this method called *userTableName*.  If you have a different name for the user name column in the *Occupant* table then you would also specify that in the parameter *userNameColumn*. Also the identification column name used in your table would be specified in *userIdColumn*.  There are techniques for including the SimpleMembership database with your your own database and the details depend upon if you are using the code-first or database-first approach. Out of the box SimpleMembership is code-first.